# Office 365 branding with powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I want to automate the steps for creating a new Office 365 tenant and I would like to know if it's possible to brand an Office 365 tenant with powershell. For example saving the banner and logo pictures in a local folder and upload them to Office 365 with powershell. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not automate the whole tenant creation process using powershell;

1. Powershell and all other APIs requires the tenant to be created at first place, so you can connect to it and hence start playing around with remote powershell.
2. you will need to add custom domain (the one will be used and assigned to all O365 services), this requires adding txt DNS records apart of the domain ownership validation, thankfully managing doamins using powershell is something doable, please [check this reference for complete information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/new-msoldomain?view=azureadps-1.0)
3. Inspecting the MSOnline reference page (the one has all powershell module commands), there is no command that allows you to customize the sign-in page look using powershell, [check this reference please](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/?view=azureadps-1.0#msonline).